# Can't load third party library using Cocoa Pods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've loaded many pods without issue, but this one is causing an issue.

Here is my Podfile:

[image]

And the install appears to go well:

[image]

Yet I'm getting an error when I go to import in my View Controller:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was I named my XCode Project the same name as the library I was trying to import.  This created confusion for the compiler.  You can see this in the third image I attached.